# Scrapy json response: wildcards and scraping references

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a JSON response with Scrapy. I was wondering if it is possible to scrape a wildcard path in a JSON that finds the nested value "Metro" and pulls the "distance" within that hiearchy.

In the JSON, there are several poi objects, but I am only interested in the Metro one, and the  distance to the Metro. Please see below for the example I am trying to scrape.

I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work as the wildcard doesn't function and the reference is incorrect. I am used to XPATH scraping, so hoping there is some easy way to do this?

```
loader.add_value('Metro', jsonresponse["poi"][*][["name"]== "Metro"]["distance"])
```

The full JSON:

```
"poi":[
      {
         "distance":1469.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":1948,
         "url":"",
         "lon":14,
         "time":1890,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/263",
         "name":"Metro"
      },
      {
         "distance":2163.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":4371,
         "url":"",
         "lon":14,
         "time":4200,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/155",
         "name":"Tram"
      },
      {
         "distance":33.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":40,
         "url":"",
         "lon":14,
         "time":36,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/198",
         "name":"Bus MHD"
      },
      {
         "distance":1413.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":2615,
         "url":"",
         "lon":14,
         "time":2382,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/169",
         "name":"Vlak"
      },
      {
         "distance":487.0,
         "description":"Bankomat",
         "walkDistance":968,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":943,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/28",
         "name":"Bankomat"
      },
      {
         "distance":473.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":614,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":574,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/122",
         "name":"Police"
      },
      {
         "distance":188.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":250,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":253,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/72",
         "name":"Apothecary"
      },
      {
         "distance":286.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":400,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":381,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/144",
         "name":"Sport"
      },
      {
         "distance":286.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":400,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":381,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/133",
         "name":"Restaurant"
      },
      {
         "distance":64.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":233,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":216,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/423",
         "name":"Supermarket"
      },
      {
         "distance":168.0,
         "description":"Station",
         "walkDistance":320,
         "url":"url",
         "lon":14,
         "time":295,
         "lat":50,
         "imgUrl":"https://api.mapy.cz/poiimg/icon/142",
         "name":"School"
      }
```

Comment: Post a complete json sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, than you can go with this:

```
distance = [x['distance'] for x in jsonresponse['poi'] if x['name'] == 'Metro'][0]
```